# Pymodbus :: RTU :: Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalValue)

Tags: python, pymodbus

I am trying to read the holding register but getting this error - Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalValue)

I have checked the register and connection using MODscan software-(My RTU device is connected to laptop via RS485-USB conveter.

Any little help is appreciated.

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient
client=ModbusSerialClient(port='COM3',method='rtu',
                          baudrate=19200,bytesize=8,
                          parity="N",stopbits=1,
                          timeout=0.3)
connect=client.connect()

if connect==True:
    print('Connected')
    print(client.read_holding_registers(address=3020,count=5,slave=1,unit=0))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the device documentation?

Comment: Thanks for your response  @Bosz

I am using Schnider 6400NG+ as a device with RS485.
I have connected device RS485 to (USB-RS485) converter(Elmeasure USB-RS485 converter). then USB to laptop port

Comment: Are you sure register 3020 exists? It is not listed in the [Modbus map](https://ckm-content.se.com/ckmContent/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0691H00000DwnEIQAZ). Also, it seems to me that `unit=0` should be removed? Also note that the default parity is Even.